# Which regex allows me to match characters and digits from specific String like GIVEN_CHAR_VAL":"AKRONIS387226279863_NXUS0000000016092126"

Tags: regex

Which regex allows me to match characters and digits from String `GIVEN_CHAR_VAL":"AKRONIS387226279863_NXUS0000000016092126"`

I tried

```
GIVEN_CHAR_VAL":"(.*)"
```

but doesn't work correct.
Any ideas?

Comment: what exactly do you want to match? taking your example, do you wish to extract the product key portion before or after the underscore, or both, or something completely different ?

Comment: Your regex returns, in capturing group 1, AKRONIS387226279863_NXUS0000000016092126  What do you want returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to match alphanumeric characters, use `\w` rather than `.`:

```
GIVEN_CHAR_VAL":"(\w*)"
```

Comment: \w will also match underscores and, depending on the flavor, which the OP did not specify, a plethora of unicode characters.

Comment: Now Match count: 3
Match[1][0]=ADHOC_CHAR_VAL":"PLENED387226279863_NXUS0000000016092126
Match[1][1]=PLENED387226279863_NXUS0000000016092126
Match[2][0]=ADHOC_CHAR_VAL":"
Match[2][1]=
Match[3][0]=ADHOC_CHAR_VAL":"
Match[3][1]=

Comment: There's no `ADHOC_CHAR_VAL` in your example, I don't know why that's showing up in your results.

Comment: my fault, RegExp Tester returns me 3 counts 
Match[1[0]=GIVEN_CHAR_VAL":"AKRONIS387226279863_NXUS0000000021805183
Match[1][1]=AKRONIS387226279863_NXUS0000000021805183
Match[2][0]=GIVEN_CHAR_VAL":"
Match[2][1]=
Match[3][0]=GIVEN_CHAR_VAL":"
Match[3][1]=

Comment: Please update your question with the full input data and what you expect to return.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested regex works for me, but have you tried:

```
GIVEN_CHAR_VAL":"(.*?)"
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you actually want to match?

.* will give you the entire set  AKRONIS387226279863_NXUS0000000016092126

\w+ as suggested above will do the same because it accepts '_'

If you are trying to match everything except the underscore try something more specific like [A-Z0-9]+ though you will end up with two matches because of the intervening underscore.

Comment: actually I want to match only AKRONIS387226279863_NXUS0000000021805183

Comment: Then I Barmar's answer is the best one.  (I.e. use \w instead of .)  Although you didn't state it in your question, I'm assuming that your problem is that you are capturing the final quotation mark.  If that's not what is going wrong, it would be useful if you could post some more information.